# Class Serialization Design

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to serialize 3 different objects into 3 different XMLs. Further, i will deserialize it.

My Class Design:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CarsPersistence cars = new CarsPersistence()
        {
            Cars = new Car[]
            {
                new Car{ Name = "Car1", Speed = 201},
                new Car{ Name = "Car2", Speed = 202},
                new Car{ Name = "Car3", Speed = 203},
                new Car{ Name = "Car4", Speed = 204},
                new Car{ Name = "Car5", Speed = 205},
            }
        };

        WaysPersistence ways = new WaysPersistence()
        {
            Ways = new Way[]
            {
                new Way{Number = 100, Length = 200 },
                new Way{Number = 101, Length = 201 },
                new Way{Number = 102, Length = 202 },
                new Way{Number = 103, Length = 203 },
                new Way{Number = 104, Length = 204 },
                new Way{Number = 105, Length = 205 },
                new Way{Number = 106, Length = 206 },
                new Way{Number = 107, Length = 207 },
            }
        };

        CarsWaysPersistence carsWays = new CarsWaysPersistence()
        {
            CarsWays = new KeyValuePair<Car, Way>[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<Car, Way>(cars.Cars[0], ways.Ways[2]),
                new KeyValuePair<Car, Way>(cars.Cars[3], ways.Ways[1])
            }
        };
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class CarsPersistence
{
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Way
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class WaysPersistence
{
    public Way[] Ways { get; set; }
}

public class CarsWaysPersistence
{
    public KeyValuePair<Car, Way>[] CarsWays { get; set; }
}
```

I will serialize 3 persistence classes (CarsPersistence, WaysPersistence, CarsWaysPersistence) in different XML files.

My problem is duplication: CarsWaysPersistence have Car and Way objects which are already consists in other XML files. Probably, i can not save reference in XML file.

How this duplication can be solved. 
Thanks

Comment: Use Dictionary instead of : public KeyValuePair<Car, Way>[] CarsWays { get; set; } : public Dictionary<Car, List<Way>> CarsWays { get; set; }

Comment: jdweng thanks but is not helps me

Comment: The List<way> should solve the duplication issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Serialize all cars.
2) Serialize all ways.
3) Use `Name` of the car as a **unique** identifier. You have to provide some unique key to `Way` as well. This would allow you to map them by the key: `<car_name, way_key>`.